# How do I use ngrok link vs ngrok standard?

Tags: ngrok

According to their [documentation](https://ngrok.com/docs/ngrok-link), I can install ngrok as a Windows service by calling

```
ngrok service
```

However, I noticed in the docs, there is a [difference](https://ngrok.com/docs/ngrok-link#differences) between "standard ngrok" and "ngrok link" (the latter having the service feature set).  I cannot figure out if it's a separate download, or what.  There doesn't seem to be much information on that.

Anyone know what's up?

Answer (score 0):

It's a separate download, but it isn't publicly accessible from their website.  The company I work for is just in the process of upgrading to ngrok link, and I can't confirm at the moment, but I suspect the ngrok link download will be available when you log into the management portal with your ngrok link account.

**Update:** I can confirm now that the ngrok link download is available after logging into your ngrok link enabled account, and selecting the "Link" menu item on the left.

Answer (score 0):

PM from ngrok here. For anyone finding this question in the future, ngrok link has been retired. All the functionality is in the latest ngrok agent which is available at https://ngrok.com/download or in your favorite package manager.